# Publishing GTK4 apps on AppCenter?

Tags: appcenter, development

I've been working on a GTK4 app and was wondering if I could publish it on the AppCenter

The [official documentation](https://github.com/elementary/houston/wiki/Before-You-Publish#native-front-end) doesn't seem to say anything about GTK4 specifically, only that it must be "native". Would that include GTK4?

Comment: elementary OS is moving to GTK4 as well (some of their apps are already ported, like Calculator), so I think you will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

If it should be possible to publish as long as it fits with the elementary design standards and is packaged in flatpak format.